# Construct a table with no association (Chi-square)

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test

I have a problem in my book where I am supposed to create a 3x3 table of counts where there is no apparent association between the row and column variables. So I know the df will be 4. And thus I must find a $X^2$ small enough so that the null hypothesis will be rejected. However, trying to find 9 numbers to make the chi-square small enough seems to be difficult for me. Is there a systematic way of finding what "actual" counts to use to achieve a small $X^2$ or do I just have to resort to guess and check. Guessing and checking seems quite excessive.

Comment: Maybe you need the self-study tag since this sounds like a homework problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then you need your joint probability to be equal to the product of marginal probabilities - this will literally mean there is no association.

In other words, come up with any row totals $r_i$ and column totals $c_j$ (non-negative integers such as $\sum_{i} r_i=\sum_{j} c_j=n$).

Let every cell be ${v_i}_j=r_i*c_j/n$.

One problem here is if you require cells to be integer, too - a simple way to achieve that is scaling them up to be ${v_i}_j=r_i*c_j$.

Comment: So you're saying when doing the chi-square test, in the formula of (actual - expected)^2/expected, the "actual - expected" should = 0?

Comment: The lower the difference, the less evidence you have against the null hypothesis (which assumes that there is no association between rows and columns). Chi squared test can be seen as converting this difference into a p-value.